# How can I generate client code for .NET applications using AsyncAPI specs?

Tags: code-generation, openapi, asyncapi

The documentation for AsyncAPI says

> Generators are available for mainstream applications like Java, .NET, Javascript, etc. You can check out [this](https://github.com/asyncapi/generator) repo for more information.

However, there is no mention of .NET here. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

When you come from OpenAPI and it's [OpenAPITools/openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) one of the main differences is that the [AsyncAPI generator](https://github.com/asyncapi/generator) allows anyone to create code generators, those we call `templates`.

You can find that list of public available templates [here](https://github.com/search?q=topic%3Aasyncapi%20topic%3Agenerator%20topic%3Atemplate).

The AsyncAPI generator itself is written in JS as is the templates, however, they can generate anything you would like. Documentation, config files, etc.

For .NET we currently only have [one template, and that is for the NATS protocol](https://github.com/asyncapi/dotnet-nats-template).

It varies which protocols are supported by which templates, as some support more protocols and others only one.

If none of the existing templates are of use to you, I highly [recommend you author your own](https://github.com/asyncapi/generator/blob/master/docs/authoring.md)! Cause we really need more templates.